# When I designed an interface with multiple return valuse on AllJoyn Framework, an exception is thrown by the call. I don't know why

Tags: java, android, alljoyn

The interface with two return values :

```
@BusInterface(name = "com.cykj.alljoyn.servicetest.MutipleRVInterface")
public interface MutipleRVInterface {
 //多返回值
 public class Values {
    @Position(0)
    public int startTime;
    @Position(1)
    public int endTime;
   }
 @BusMethod(replySignature = "ii")
 public Values  getTime() throws BusException;
}
```

A class implements the interface and BusObject and on the AllJoyn Service:

```
class ServiceTest implements MutipleRVInterface, BusObject {

    @Override
    public Values  getTime() throws BusException {
        Values  t = new Values ();
        t.startTime = 11;
        t.endTime = 22;
        return t;
    }
}
```

The client uses the service object:

```
try {
      MutipleRVInterface.Values time = mutipleRVInterface.getTime();
      logResult(time.startTime + "-" + time.endTime);
    } catch (BusException e) {
      LogResult(e.getMessage());
      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

When I called the method of MutipleRVInterface,an exception is thrown.

```
02-20 14:00:17.209 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err: org.alljoyn.bus.ErrorReplyBusException: org.alljoyn.Bus.ErStatus
02-20 14:00:17.209 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.methodCall(Native Method)
02-20 14:00:17.210 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.access$300(ProxyBusObject.java:35)
02-20 14:00:17.210 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject$Handler.invoke(ProxyBusObject.java:264)
02-20 14:00:17.210 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at $Proxy1.getTime(Native Method)
02-20 14:00:17.210 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest.BusMethodTActivity$BusHandler.handleMessage(BusMethodTActivity.java:584)
02-20 14:00:17.210 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
02-20 14:00:17.211 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-20 14:00:17.211 20695-20954/com.cykj.alljoyn.clienttest W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

How can I solve the problem? where is wrong in the code?

ps:This is an Android Project with using AllJoyn Framework. And I am not very good at English, the question may not be described clear.Try to be understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user-defined data types in AllJoyn methods.

You need to define both positions and signatures of the custom datatype and use it with **'r'** signature which stands for STRUCT.

So in your case the code should be something like;

```
@BusInterface(name = "com.cykj.alljoyn.servicetest.MutipleRVInterface")
public interface MutipleRVInterface {
 //多返回值
 public class Values {
    @Position(0)
    @Signature("i")
    public int startTime;
    @Position(1)
    @Signature("i")        
    public int endTime;
   }
 @BusMethod(replySignature="r")
 public Values  getTime() throws BusException;
}
```

> | r | STRUCT | User-defined type whose fields are annotated with
>   `Position`annotation and `Signature`

You can find more info about Signatures in https://allseenalliance.org/docs/api/java/org/alljoyn/bus/annotation/Signature.html or just review the `org/alljoyn/bus/annotation/Signature.java`code

Comment: It's not useful. When I set replySignature="r", there is a error that the return Status is "BAD_ANNOTATION" when registerBusObject.

Comment: @Wing.L I have edited the signature. You can also check ./alljoyn_java/test/org/alljoyn/bus/AddressBookInterface.java class for further usage.